# Advise on resolving pseudo-class compatibility for IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, modernizr, pseudo-class, selectivizr

I have used pseudo-classes in the project, that i am currently working on, and since it is already javascript heavy I am trying to avoid using selectivizr. Is there are way making psedoclass compatible with IE8? Is it possible to use Modernizr to resolve this issue?

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which pseudo-classes? The basic ones like `:link`, `:hover`, `:first-child` all work with IE8.

Comment: I am working with first-child, last-child and nth-child. So I have issues with last-child and nth-child.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for `css-lastchild` with Modernizr (you'll find it in the *Non-core detects* section) and customize your styles if the browser doesn't support `css-lastchild` - which would mean it doesn't support any other of the CSS3 selectors either, which are:

- `:root`
- `:nth-child()`
- `:nth-last-child()`
- `nth-of-type`
- `nth-last-of-type()`
- `:last-child`
- `:first-of-type`
- `:last-of-type`
- `:only-child`
- `:only-of-type`
- `:empty`
- `:target`
- `:enabled`
- `:disabled`
- `:checked`
- `:not()`.